# Pymongo Update: is it possible insert field with '$currentDate' only one time?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, database

I work in Pymongo and would like to create 2 types of time-Fields for a Document: **time_creation** and **time_update**.

1. **time_creation**: it is created only in the first time. If I update the DB, it does not change (it must be constant).
2. **time_update**: it must be updated every time that I update the DB.

To **time_update** I use:

```
'$currentDate':{'time_update': { '$type': 'date' }}
```

and that works fine. I would like an identical structure for **time_creation**, i.e., I would like to use **'$currentDate'** and I do not want to use **datetime**! I know that the structure:

```
'$setOnInsert':{'time_creation': datetime.utcnow()}
```

works fine. But I don't want to use this. I would like to know if there is a way to do this with **'$currentDate'** and **'$type': 'date'**

Comment: It's a fair ask as I have often wondered why `$currentDate` was applied as a "top level" update operation and not as something on the "right side" of the defined field inside a `$set` or `$setOnInsert`, or even a `$max` for that matter. But the "top level" ( and "left side" ) implementation is why it cannot be done, and why getting the "client date" is really the only way with a `$setOnInsert`. I'd vote for a JIRA issue on this though.

Comment: And if we use **'$setOnInsert'** is there a way to use **'$type': 'date'**  ? It seems that this is not possible. I did some research and unsuccessful attempts.

Comment: To be more direct about my earlier comment, this is not supported at all. The only way you can do this is with the `datetime.utcnow()` as you already have. I agree such an operation make infinitely more sense than the `$currentDate` construct, but right now that is all there is, and therefore it cannot be applied on "upserts" alone.